# Using log4j with JBoss 7.2 (EAP 6.1-Alpha, not JBoss 6) with SAR

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss7.x, sar

I have tried the followings but none works - My SAR deploys fine but I do not see any log4j message, as if log4j initialization never happens.

A) Put exclusion of `org.apache.log4j` in my `jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml`
B) Included a copy of `log4j.xml` in my `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration` sub-directory
C) Set the `-Dlog4j.configuration` option in my `standalone.sh`.

I also tried to include the log4j.xml directly under the META-INF of my 'SAR', along with the `log4j-1.2.15.jar` that I use with my apps.  In addition, I also tried to zip up my `log4j.xml` into a jar file and place it in my SAR along with other jars. (I have added the name of these jars in my deployment descriptor) All efforts failed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Matthew

Update: I have added the follow flag to standalone.sh

> -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

and now I see the following error:

> 18:44:31,989 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.abc.mbean.listenerImpl).
>   18:44:31,990 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Since I have placed the `log4j.xml` under my standalone/configuration + pack the log4j.xml with my log4j.jar in my SAR already, now can I let JBoss know my log4j configuration?

Many Thanks!

Matthew

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? What is your final goal? JBoss uses slf4j to manage logging, and it is configured to use log4j connectors out of the box. Are you just not seeing your log messages show up, or do you really want to replace the JBoss logging implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration` directory is not on your class path so log4j will not see a configuration file there. You'll need to package your log4j.xml in the SAR. Probably in the `META-INF` directory of the SAR.

Answer (score 0):

Tried both the ways mentioned in the thread below. Worked fine for me.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/219871